# What algorithm should I use to train an antichess agent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, monte-carlo-tree-search, proximal-policy-optimization, minimax, chess

I will implement an antichess agent and am not sure about which algorithm to use. My current candidates are minimax with alpha-beta pruning, MCTS and proximal policy optimization.

Should I consider antichess just as regular chess in the selection of algorithms? Which algorithm could be expected to give better results?

Antichess, also known as suicide chess, is a chess variant where the objective is to lose all your pieces or be stalemated rather than checkmating your opponent.
For more info: https://lichess.org/variant/antichess

Comment: Maybe link what antichess is? I'm assuming some version of chess where the goal is to force your opponent to put you into check? If there are any variants, say which one.